# Google Places Auto complete limit to only 1 state

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the Places AutoComplete API, to get results just for a single State and not all the possible matches in different places for example:

If the Input is Manhattan, right now it shows as Results:

Manhattan, New York, NY, USA
Manhattan Beach, CA, USA
Manhattan, IL, USA
Manhattan, MT, USA

However, I want to limit to see only results, for example, to the State of NY, that way the response should be only the first hit (Manhattan, New York, NY, USA) and not the rest of the previous example.

At the moment my API Request is:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Manhattan&types=(regions)&components=country:us&key=[MY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Manhattan&types=(regions)&components=country:us&key=%5BMY) API KEY]

I tried changing components=country:us to components=state:ny but got errors only, is there a way to get this behavior and have it filter only by the state.

Kind Regards,

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error at all only getting hits from all the country not limited to a single state

Answer (score 0):

`country` is the only component mentioned in the Autocomplete components filtering documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#components

Trying to do component filtering for other types (e.g. `administrative_area_level_1` which would represent a US state) will result in an `INVALID_REQUEST` response.

---

The best option you have right now would be to filter the result list based on the received state data.

Comment: Hi I tried the end Point: 

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Manhattan&types=(regions)&components=administrative_area_level_1 = ny&key=[myAPIKey]

got this result: 

{
 "predictions": [],
"status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}

any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just add prefix of the state (abbr) in the input field prior to making the request. you can show a different field where the user inputs the search and populate the input field with the state prefix when requesting.